# MGLEARN Plot KNN classification doesn't show the plot

Tags: python, plot, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I am moving the first ML steps reading the book [Introduction to Machine Learning](https://books.google.it/books?id=1-4lDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Introduction%20to%20Machine%20Learning&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv8YqiodjXAhXkKsAKHQ_PAPAQ6wEITzAF#v=onepage&q=Introduction%20to%20Machine%20Learning&f=false).
I am trying to generate the picture of the snippet "**In [10]**" that you can find on **[this](https://github.com/amueller/introduction_to_ml_with_python/blob/master/02-supervised-learning.ipynb)** page, but it down't work. When I say that it doesn't work I mean that nothing it's been shown when I hit "run" (neither an error message).

What's wrong with the following code?

I think that I am missing something like plt.show() code but looking on Google it seems that mglearn doen't need/have this construction.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mglearn.plots

X, y = mglearn.datasets.make_forge()
mglearn.discrete_scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], y)
plt.legend(["Class 0", "Class 1"], loc=4)
plt.xlabel("First feature")
plt.ylabel("Second feature")
print("X.shape: {}".format(X.shape))
#plt.show()


mglearn.plots.plot_knn_classification(n_neighbors=1)
```

I am using Python 3.6.3.

Comment: Call show after plot_knn_classification.

Comment: @sascha I can't find a show command for Mglearn...what's the syntax?

Comment: You use matplotlibs! Consider reading a basic matplotlib tutorial. Do ```plt.show()``` right after ```plot_knn_classification```. And consider using jupyter-notebooks, like this tutorial probably is build for.

Comment: @sascha great...it works, thank you!

Comment: Good. See [here](https://github.com/amueller/introduction_to_ml_with_python/blob/master/mglearn/plot_knn_classification.py) that this function you use is just a small wrapper calling matplotlib too (besides some ML-processings). But as can be seen there is nothing to actually show the plot. Therefore this call after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @Sascha tips I get the following working code:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mglearn.plots

X, y = mglearn.datasets.make_forge()


mglearn.plots.plot_knn_classification(n_neighbors=1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use display function than plt.show().

```
import mglearn
from IPython.display import display

X,y=mglearn.datasets.make_forge()
knn=mglearn.plots.plot_knn_classification(n_neighbors=1)
display(knn)
```

Then, we'll have the picture the same as the book.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbQrh.jpg)

If you use plt.show(), the picture will be different.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNuzB.jpg)